# LineLegend with dashed and coloured line

Tags: legending

I would like to create a LineLegend that incorporates both coloured and dashed lines.  I expected this to be simple, but I'm missing something.

The below will give the LineLegend with either linestyle defined, or the colour defined - how do I do both?

```
LineLegend[{Line, Dashed, Dotted}, {"red line", "green dashed", 
  "blue dotted"}]
LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"red line", "green dashed", 
  "blue dotted"}]
```

I tried

```
LineLegend[{{Dashed, Red}, {Line, Blue}, {Green, Dotted}}, {"red", 
  "green", "blue"}]
```

but got no output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Line` is not a directive. You can remove it.

```
LineLegend[{Red, {Dashed, Green}, {Dotted, Blue}}, 
  {"red line", "green dashed", "blue dotted"}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `Dashing[{}]` to get a solid line:

```
LineLegend[Thread[Directive[{Red, Green, Blue}, {Dashing[{}], Dashed, Dotted}]],
  {"red line", "green dashed", "blue dotted"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to create a LineLegend that incorporates both coloured
>   and dashed lines.

```
LineLegend[{Directive[{Dashed, Red}], {Line, Blue}, {Green, 
   Dotted}}, {"red", "green", "blue"}]
```

[image]